# Identifying the elastic limit?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain, linear-systems

**Consider this problem**

[image]

I understand that the elastic limit is the point at which the material no longer elastically deforms, that is it doesn't return to its original shape. However, I am struggling to identify this point

$A$ must represent the **limit of proportionality** and $D$ must represent **permanent deformation**. Hence $B$ or $C$ must represent  the elastic limit. The answers state that $B$ is correct. However, can we be certain that past this point the material is no longer elastic? To me $C$ seems more intuitive as we can visually see that here the materials unloading curve is different from the loading curve.

So why is the solution $B$? Clear workings would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me as if the relationship is linear above A, and that it deviates from a straight line only just before B.

Comment: There is not enough information to determine if B is the elastic limit.  One would have to back down on the stress, starting at B to see if there is any residual strain when the stress is reduced to zero.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection it would appear that the limit of proportionality (stress vs strain graph a straight line through the origin) is possibly at $A$ but could be between $A$ and $B$ as long as the point is on the straight line part of the graph.

$C$ is beyond the elastic limit because as the stress is reduced the material suffers a permanent deformation which is represented by $OD$ when the stress has been reduced to zero.

Thus, it is possible that $B$ is the elastic limit which will mean that as the stress is reduced, the strain will follow the line $BAO$.
Note that around $B$ the gradient of the graph changes a great deal such that a small increase in the stress produces a larger increase in the strain than at lower stresses which is indicative of plastic deformation for ductile material.

Comment: Does that mean at exactly the point of the elastic limit, the material still returns to its original shape?

Comment: Any strain greater than that at the elastic limit results in plastic deformation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so,
A is for sure the point where the proportionality ceases, and force applied is no longer in proportion with the deformation (Hooke's Law is rendered useless after this point)

The controversy at hand is between B and C
But the thing is, the material still partially retains it's elastic nature temporarily after B
Its at a stage where its both, plastic and elastic

we know this because the stress continues with strain between B and C

In my opinion, B must be the elastic limit
C on the other hand must be the upper yield point because once the strain continues beyond this point, the body fractures and hence the steep drop to show that all stress ceases